# What does that * mean in the text font size parameter of display.newText in Corona?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

In this display.newText parameter, what does 16*2 mean? Thanks.

```
    local display_txt=display.newText("Wait",0,0,native.SystemFont,16*2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last argument to [display.newText](http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/displaynewtext) is the size. In this case, the programmer is setting a size of 32 but has chosen to express it as 16*2 for some reason.